# How to send iOS push notifications using FCM(Firebase cloud messaging) in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I was able to send push notification using FCM at xamarin native android.
But i am not getting any resource for enable ios Push/receive notifications from FCM.
Please help me to do this. I tried FCM plugin for ios . but not working.

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful description of your problem.  What specifically did you try, and what specific errors are you getting?  There are many articles online about using FCM with iOS.

Comment: have you enabled remote notifications and push notifications from entilements???

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I think you can use [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/) to send iOS push notification using FCM.

And there is a [detailed guideline](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#about-firebase-cloud-messaging) about how to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging on Xamamrin.iOS.

For creating push notification certificates and settings in iOS app, you can have a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#register-your-app-for-push-notifications).